# Docker download code from git and run php internal server

Tags: php, docker

I want to download a public github project and run a project file through internal php server, through docker.

This is my file so far:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/mygit src
WORKDIR src

CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "-t", "/src/src/examples/image.php"]
```

The process does not show up in docker ps when I run:

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myimage
```

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` to obtain a list with running and stopped containers, then find the container id you wish to debug, execute `docker logs containerId` and provide the output in your original post.

Comment: docker logs 86ac2cbd6f11
[Tue Apr 16 22:36:31 2019] 172.17.0.1:59284 [200]: /
[Tue Apr 16 22:41:30 2019] 172.17.0.1:59288 [200]: /
[Tue Apr 16 22:41:30 2019] 172.17.0.1:59292 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
[Tue Apr 16 22:41:37 2019] 172.17.0.1:59290 [200]: /

Comment: Strange,now when I run `docker run -d -p 8081:8081 myimage` it seems to work, docker ps shows the process, but now I got no information sent error. Docker logs is empty now.

Comment: Can you share your github link project so I can tell you exactly what your issue is? 8080 may be already used in your docker host..

Comment: https://github.com/douma/langtons-ant. I try to run CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "/src/src/examples/image.php"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/douma/langtons-ant src
WORKDIR src
ENTRYPOINT ["php"]
CMD ["-S", "0.0.0.0:8080","/src/src/examples/image.php"]
```

**Note** I don't know php but checking your github project's readme I think you do not need the `-t` argument.

I also added `ENTRYPOINT` command to make your `Dockerfile` clearer. For differences check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile).

The build and run commands should be the same as these you posted.

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myimage
```